# Rational functions examples

Tags: complex-analysis, rational-functions

I have been briefly looking into rational functions. The following 2 examples seem obvious, although I cannot think of a concrete explanation:

$e^{(1+z/3)}$,    $cos(z+1/z^2)$ are not rational functions

I am assuming this follows because $e^z$ and $cos(z)$ are not rational functions!? But why is this true?

Comment: A rational function is a quotient of two polynomials, and the denominator polynomial is not the zero one. That's all. None of the two functions you wrote is of this form.

Comment: @DonAntonio Correct, but there is that subtlety that two functions may look as they have completely different "form", yet they have the same values and are therefore the same function.

Comment: @user8734617 Not in this case and over an infinite field.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the behaviour on the reals:

The second one is not constant yet bounded, impossible for a rational function. Alternatively, it vanishes infinitely many times on $\Bbb R$, also impossible.

The first one increases at exponential speed, when rational functions should be $O(x^k)$ for some $k\in \Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible answers here.

Here is one hint: if $f(z)=\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}$, where $p,q$ are polynomials, then $f(z)$ can have *at most finitely many zeros*, or it *is* zero. This comes from the fact that the zeros of $f$ are the zeros of $p$ that are not zeros of $q$, and there are at most $\deg p$ of them.

A consequence: a rational function can have each value $C$ for *at most finitely many $z$*, or $f$ is equal to a constant $C$. You prove that by applying the statement above to the (rational) function $f-C$.

Now... For how many $z$ is $\cos(z+\frac{1}{z^2})=0$, i.e. can you solve equations $z+\frac{1}{z^2}=\pi/2+k\pi$ for every $k\in\mathbb Z$? (Yes, you can, because those equations reduce to cubic equations in $\mathbb C$, which always have solutions.)

Also... For how many values $z$ is $e^{1+\frac{z}{3}}=1$? (Solve the equations $1+\frac{z}{3}=2k\pi i$ for $k\in\mathbb Z$).